# How to reassign a value based on user input in order for it to be updated and move around on the board I'm making

Tags: python

**My problem:**
The problem that I am having is trying to use the user's input to validate whether or not they can move up, down, left, or right on the playboard I made.
With this being said, every time I try moving a direction, using WASD, it redirects me to random locations rather than the correct direction intended. I also noticed that no matter where I am placed on the board, it tends to keep placing me in those same exact locations no matter where I am on the board.

**What I have tried:**

I've tried evaluating the values I inputted and that did not help me. I've also tried updating it in a different way but didn't know how to go about it. After I couldn't figure it out, I reached out for help via Google and threads on here but couldn't grasp or understand what was properly happening.

**Here is the code I have so far:**

```
def CommandPlayer(player, board):
    VALID_INPUTS = ["W","A","S","D","Q"]
    while True: #input validation loop
        userInput = input("Enter a direction (WASD or Q to quit): ").upper()
        if userInput in VALID_INPUTS:
            break
    if userInput == "Q":
        input("Goodbye!")
        sys.exit(0)

    #capture the current player location
    row = player['row']
    col = player['col']

    #remove player from board
    player['row'] = row
    player['col'] = col
    board[row][col] = "."
    

    #if statement that increment or decrement row/col based on input
    #there will be four of these
    if userInput == "W":
        if row == 0:    #if row is currently 0:
            row += -1    #set row to max row position
        else:           #else:
            row -= 1    #row -= 1
               
    elif userInput == "A":
        if col == 0:    #if col is currently 0:
            col += -1    #set col to max col position
        else:           #else:
            col -= 1    #col -= 1
        
    elif userInput == "S":
        if row == -1:   #if row is at max:
            row = 0     #row = 0
        else:           #else:
            row += 1    #row += 1
        
    elif userInput == "D":
        if col == -1:   #if col is at max:
            col = 0     #col = 0
        else:           #else:
            col += 1    #col += 1
    #put player on board
    #update row and col in player
    board[row][col] = "@"

    return board, player
```

**Representation of player input on board:**

Here you will see a picture of the board. The circled @ on the board is where it was randomly places, which is good! Though the other @ is where it moved once I input W, which is wrong.

[Board Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vLomv.png)

Comment: You're setting ` player['row'] = row` and `player['col'] = col` *before* you actually change `row` and `col` - why do you expect anything in `player` to change, then?

Comment: Is there a chance you evaluate random position for the plater after exiting the CommandPlayer() function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

---

### Explanation

You are `updating the board` with the `new col and row values` but `not the correspoding player attributes`. That's why you are seeing more than one times the player(@) on board. The actual player(@) never moves, you just change the character from dot(.) to @ somewhere else in the board.

---

### Solution

Update player position after if statements, example below. You had wrote those two lines but before if statements.

```
...
#put player on board
#update row and col in player
board[row][col] = "@"

player['row'] = row # add this
player['col'] = col # and that

return board, player
```

*You had wrote a correct comment about it as well.*

---